# 2D Array for loop not storing values java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Can someone help to find out what I'm doing wrong here thanks.:)
It seems to be going wrong in the for loop as I can't recall the values even outside the loop. So I don't think it's storing the values but I just can't seem to find what the problem is.

```
import java.lang.Math;
```

class Calculator 
{

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int range = 20;
    int max=(range/2)
    int min=((-range)/2);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int j = min;

    int[][] table = new int[range][2];

for(int i = 0 ; i == range ; i++ )
    {

    //X coordinate
    table[i][x] = 2*j;
    System.out.println("X="+table[i][x]);

    //Y coordinate
    table[i][y] = j;
    System.out.println("Y="+table[i][y]);

    j++;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: You're not looping. The middle condition isn't true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `for(int i = 0 ; i < range ; i++ )` Basically the loop doesn't execute because i != range at the start.